# TSQL: How to calculate with value of row above and use that in the row below

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I would like to use the value of row one and use it in a calculation for row two. I would like to use the result of the caulculation of row two in the next row. And so on.

Row 1: 0 + in - out = end

Row 2: end (row 1) + in - out = end

Row 3: end (row 2) + in - out = end

Row 4: end (row 3) + in - out = end

[Result should look like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74LiQ.jpg)

I would like to calculate Start and End. I am wondering how you would solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the values you want to calculate are `start` and `end`, then you would just use cumulative sums:

```
select in, out,
       sum(in - out) over (order by id) - (in - out) as starting
       sum(in - out) over (order by id) as ending
from t;
```

You can also express the `starting` using a window farme:

```
select in, out,
       sum(in - out) over (order by id rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as starting
       sum(in - out) over (order by id) as ending
from t;
```

However, this returns a `NULL` value for the first row, and the first version is easier to type.

Answer (score 0):

Since SQL Sever 2012 you can do this.

```
SELECT SUM(In - Out) OVER(ORDER BY RowId ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS End
FROM Table
```

For the exact solution you need, you can do the following:-

```
SELECT Row, In, Out, End, 
       SUM(End - (In - Out)) OVER(ORDER BY id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Start
FROM (  SELECT  Row,
          In, Out,
          SUM(In - Out) OVER(ORDER BY Row ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS End
       FROM Table) R
```

For older versions you need to do a self join.